# How do I assign my iCloud hosted domain email address to its own mailbox?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, domain

I have a domain work email address I transferred over to iCloud a few months ago.  Since then all new email addressed to it arrives in my iCloud.com email address box. Is there a way of setting up the mail app to put my domain email address in its own mailbox and have it synched across devices?

Comment: Can't you just use rules on icloud.com to sort mails into folders?

Comment: I can, but it sucks for two reasons. First, it doesn't isolate the mail well enough. You have to remain vigilant over which email address using. You old settings and rules apply to both icloud and your custom domain. Second, a custom rule doesn't really work all that well across mobile and desktop.

Comment: You can set up rules directly on icloud.com itself, this should work for all devices then. And Mail can be configured to always use the account the mail was sent to when replying. I don't have an iCloud hosted domain so I can't test this.

Comment: Post it as an answer so you can get some points. It would be cool if you could use your SE points on a new Mac or at least a donut or something.

Comment: Are you forwarding your mails from that old address or how exactly did you "transfer" those mails? Or did you just copy them into the iCloud inbox?